# Can we get the same metrics as "hadoop fsck" from Hue?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, hue, hadoop2

Is there a way to get the following details for a given file from Hue? I mainly need the total blocks and replication factor of a given file

```
 Total blocks (validated):      183 (avg. block size 133655481 B)
 Minimally replicated blocks:   183 (100.0 %)
 Over-replicated blocks:        0 (0.0 %)
 Under-replicated blocks:       0 (0.0 %)
 Mis-replicated blocks:         0 (0.0 %)
 Default replication factor:    3
 Average block replication:     3.0
 Corrupt blocks:                0
 Missing replicas:              0 (0.0 %)
 Number of data-nodes:          12
 Number of racks:               1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hue could get some of the info from [WebHdfs](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.3.0/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/WebHDFS.html#Status_of_a_FileDirectory) if using Yarn/MR2 but right now it does not display it currently.